# How to ignore plugin on Vue CLI3 in vue.congif.js

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli

I'm using Vue cli3, and want to ignore moment.js plugin with webpack. This is the rule, but on vue.confing.js it gives an error no matter how I change it.

```
  plugins: [
        new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/^\.\/locale$/, /moment$/)
    ],
```

Comment: _"it gives an error no matter how I change it"_  what error?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You appear to be trying to use the [deprecated constructor](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/ignore-plugin/#using-regular-expressions). Try this instead and don't forget to import `webpack` into the script...

```js
const webpack = require('webpack')

module.exports = {
  configureWebpack: {
    plugins: [
      new webpack.IgnorePlugin({
        resourceRegExp: /^\.\/locale$/,
        contextRegExp: /moment$/
      })
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. This reduced my bundle size considerably. You can put this code in a vue.config.js file in your root /app directory (alongside package.json, for example).

Answer (score 3):

If you want to remove all of moment and not just the locales as the OP seemed to want, here is the required configuration:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    configureWebpack: {
        plugins: [
            new webpack.IgnorePlugin({
                resourceRegExp: /moment$/
            }),
        ]
    }
};
```

Comment: better yet, thanks! wasn't using chartsjs's moment at all. 1mb lightweight.